# SqliteDataReader doesn't work in C#?

Tags: c#, html, mysql, database, sqlite

I have some data stored in a SQLite database which I want to display on a webpage in C#. I searched for the right thing to do but only found console.writeline, and beside that the SqliteDataReader function is not working. This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:/Users/elias/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/WebSites/WebSite7/App_Data/overhoren.db"))
    {
        using (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
           command.Connection = conn;

            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                string test = ("Name: " + reader["name"] + "\tScore: " + reader["score"]);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance,

Elias

Comment: What is your *query*? I.e. you have to put `command.CommandText = "...";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you've forgot to put the actual **query** to perform:

```
  command.CommandText = "...";
```

Something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: do not hardcode connection string, move it to settings
    string connectionString = 
      @"Data Source=C:/Users/elias/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/WebSites/WebSite7/App_Data/overhoren.db";

    // var for simplicity 
    using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var command = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(conn))
        {
            command.Connection = conn;

            //TODO: put the right SQL to perform here 
            command.CommandText = 
               @"select name, 
                        score
                   from MyTable";

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
              string test = "";

              // do we have any data to read?
              //DONE: try not building string but using formatting (or string interpolation)
              if (reader.Read())
                test = $"Name: {reader["name"]}\tScore: {reader["score"]}";

              //TODO: so you've got "test" string; do what you want with it
            }
        }

        //DONE: you don't want command.ExecuteNonQuery(), but command.ExecuteReader()
        //DONE: you don't want conn.Close() - "using" will do it for you 
    }
}
```